# Spring 4 STOMP Websockets - How to realise Multichannel

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

As in the newest Spring 4 tutorial with STOMP and SockJS, we find a RequestMapping of the following kind :

**Homecontroller.java**

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
```

now I tried to realize multichannel support by modifying this requestmapping:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello/{id}")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings/{id}")
    public Greeting greetingMultichannel(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        this.info();
        Thread.sleep(300); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting(" Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
```

the MessageMapping does not work,sendTo does not deliver back to the sepecified URL.
**Although** 
I did subscribe to the right channel and the message goes out without problems, as seen in this

---

**debug log:**

Opening Web Socket... stomp.js:130
Web Socket Opened... stomp.js:130

> > > CONNECT
> > >       accept-version:1.1,1.0
> > >       heart-beat:10000,10000

stomp.js:130
<<< CONNECTED
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.1

stomp.js:130
connected to server undefined stomp.js:130
Connected: CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0

(index):23

> > > SUBSCRIBE
> > >       id:sub-0
> > >       destination:/topic/greetings/1

stomp.js:130

> > > SEND
> > >       destination:/app/hello/1
> > >       content-length:18

{"name":"textext"}

---

there should be a response but there is nothing coming back..

Can someone see what I am missing here?

cheers,
Heinrich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to pass parameters to `@SendTo`/ `@SendToUser`, placeholders on `@MessageMapping` are not available in `@SendTo` / `@SendToUser`. There's an [open Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12170) for that, keep an eye on it.

In the meantime, use the `SimpMessagingTemplate`:

```
@Autowired 
private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

@MessageMapping("/hello/{id}")
public void greetingMultichannel(HelloMessage message, @DestinationVariable("id") Long id) throws Exception {
    this.info();
    Thread.sleep(300); // simulated delay

    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings/" + id, new Greeting(" Hello, " + message.getName() + "!"));
}
```

**Update 8 September 2015:**

As of Spring 4.2, destination variable placeholders can be used in `@SendTo / @SendToUser`. This is now possible:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello/{id}")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings/{id}")
public Greeting greetingMultichannel(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    this.info();
    Thread.sleep(300); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting(" Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
}
```